# Compare values of two hashes with mixed types

Tags: perl, hash

I want to compare the hash if the key-value pairs are same in the second hash. I don't want to use smartmatch as it gives warnings.

What is the best way to compare two hashes with integers,strings and maybe also arrays in it?

```
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my $hash1={"key_str"=>"a string", "key_int"=>4};
my $hash2={"key_str"=>"b string", "key_int"=>2};

foreach my $key ( keys(%$hash1) ) {
    if ($hash1->{$key} != $hash2->{$key}) {
        print($key);
    }
}
```

the output as expected is:

```
Argument "b string" isn't numeric in numeric ne (!=) at hash_compare.pl line 8 (#1)
    (W numeric) The indicated string was fed as an argument to an operator
    that expected a numeric value instead.  If you're fortunate the message
    will identify which operator was so unfortunate.

Argument "a string" isn't numeric in numeric ne (!=) at hash_compare.pl line 8 (#1)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, Perl does not have types. It does not distinguish between strings and numbers (on the outside).

Furthermore, it does not make a difference between numbers and strings on this level. The *numerical context* and *string context* matters if you check what's greater or less than. Consider this:

```
my $foo = 200;
my $bar = 99;
print $foo > $bar ? $foo : $bar;
```

Obviously it will print `200`, because 200 is numerically larger than 99.

```
my $foo = 200;
my $bar = 99;
print $foo gt $bar ? $foo : $bar;
```

But this will print `99`, because `9` is alphanumerically (as in string) greater than `2`. It compared the numbers of the code points for the characters.

But if **all you want to do is check for inequality, the `ne` operator is fine**. Even when you are not sure whether there are things other than numbers in your input.

```
foreach my $key ( keys(%$hash1) ) {
    if ($hash1->{$key} ne $hash2->{$key}) {
        print($key);
    }
}
```

`eq` (and `ne`) are smart enough to see if a number was initially a string or a number without quotes, because the internal representation of those differs.

**Warning, technical details ahead.**

Scalar values are saved in _SV_s. These in terms can contain different things. There's a special internal type for simple integers called *IV*, and also one called *PV* for strings. Perl internally converts between those two as needed when you use numbers inside of strings, or vise versa.

You can get some debugging information about the internal representation of data with `Dump` from [Devel::Peek](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Peek).

```
use Devel::Peek;

Dump("01");
Dump(01);
```

This will output:

```
SV = PV(0x19560d0) at 0x19327d0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,READONLY,IsCOW,pPOK)
  PV = 0x1c94fd0 "01"\0
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 10
  COW_REFCNT = 0
SV = IV(0x19739b0) at 0x19739c0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (IOK,READONLY,pIOK)
  IV = 1
```

As you can see, the first one is a string, and the second one is a number. 
But if we do this

```
print "01" eq 01;
```

there is no output, because the `01` is an integer and will be converted to `"1"` for comparison. Since the `0` of `"01"` is not equal to `1`, nothing gets printed.

---

If the values of your data structures are more complex, you need to walk the structure. Each type of element needs to have its own handling. There could be array references, hash references, scalar references, scalars, glob references, [dualvars](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#dualvar) and so on. There might be objects that you want to treat specially.

I suggest taking a look at how [Test::Deep](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Deep) implements this. If you decide to use it in production code (and not a unit test), you can use [Test::Deep::NoTest](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Deep::NoTest).

Comment: Much depends on whether you want `"1"` and `"01"` etc. to compare as equal or unequal.

Comment: @Borodin that's true. But `eq` takes care of that, because of the internal representation. I think it's aware that `"1"` is an SV internally, and `1` is an IV. See this example: `say 01 eq 1; say 01 eq "1"; say "01" eq "1"; say "01" eq 1;`

Comment: Yes, but my point is that the OP may (or may not) want `"1"` to *match* `"01"` and, indeed `"1000E-3"`. There are two behaviours, and in the case of a *dualvar* the results may be different.

Comment: @Borodin in that case, they'd have to adhere to my second point and build a lot of stuff themselves. There's `is_dual` from Scalar::Util to recognize _dualvar_s. Interestingly, Test::Deep does not do that. `cmp_deeply(dualvar(1337, 'bar'), dualvar(1337, 'foo'))` will fail because `foo` is not `bar`. If the numbers are different but the strings are the same, it will pass. It never looks at the number part. Probably because Test::Deep also uses `eq` on non-refs.

Comment: @Borodin I just checked the open issues for Test::Deep. There is no mention of dualvars there. Have you ever encountered this in real life?

Comment: I'm sorry. I complicated things by mentioning *dualvar* at all. The issue I was trying to raise is that *perhaps* the string `"1"`, the integer `1`, and the (probably double) `1.0` need to be distinguished. I usually just insist that you mustn't use numeric values as hash keys without pushing them through `sprintf` with a fixed format. I'm surprised that there appears to be nothing written about this, as it involves floating-point precision as well as the string representation. Imagine `++$hash{$Math::Trig::pi}`!

Answer (score 2):

You can [`use Scalar::Util qw( looks_like_number );`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#looks_like_number) to determine if the value is a number or a string. `Scalar::Util` is a standard module that is included with Perl. For a list of standard modules, see [`perldoc perlmodlib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# always use these two
use strict;
use warnings;

# handle errors in open and close
use autodie; # See http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html

use Scalar::Util  qw( looks_like_number );

my $hash1={"key_str"=>"a string", "key_int"=>4};
my $hash2={"key_str"=>"b string", "key_int"=>2};

foreach my $key ( keys(%$hash1) ) {
    if( looks_like_number( $hash1->{$key} ) && looks_like_number( $hash2->{$key} ) ){
        if ($hash1->{$key} != $hash2->{$key}) {
            print "number value of $key is different\n";
        }
    }else{
        if ($hash1->{$key} ne $hash2->{$key}) {
            print "string value of $key is different\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've written a program that doesn't use any module. I've tested below program for many cases, worked fine, but if you find any case where it fails then please let me know.

Always use `ne` to compare if you are not sure of datatype to be compared. `!=` works only for integers, `ne` for integers and strings both.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my $hash1 = {
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => [1, 2, 2],
    'key3' => {1=>1, 2=> [5, 7]},
};

my $hash2 = {
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => [1, 2, 2],
    'key3' => {1=>1, 2=> [5, 7]},
};

my $is_same = 0;
$is_same = compare($hash1, $hash2);

if ($is_same) {
    say "Same";
} else {
    say "Not same";
}

sub compare {
    my ($value1, $value2) = @_;
    my $is_same = 1;

    if (ref($value1) eq "ARRAY") {
        if (is_same_sized_array($value1, $value2)) {
            foreach (my $i = 0; $i < @$value1; $i++) {
                if (ref $value1->[$i] eq ref $value2->[$i]) {
                    $is_same = compare($value1->[$i], $value2->[$i]);
                    return 0 unless $is_same;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } elsif (ref($value1) eq "HASH") {
        if (is_same_sized_array([keys %$value1], [keys %$value2])) {
            foreach my $key (sort keys %$value1) {
                if (exists $value2->{$key} && ref $value1->{$key} eq ref $value2->{$key}) {
                    $is_same = compare($value1->{$key}, $value2->{$key});
                    return 0 unless $is_same;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        if ($value1 ne $value2) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return $is_same;
}

sub is_same_sized_array {
    my ($arr1, $arr2) = @_;
    return (@$arr1 == @$arr2) || 0;
}
```